# GCC flag for emulating floating point operations in software on ARMv8 platform with neon FPU

Tags: floating-point, embedded-linux, arm64, neon, fixed-point

**Background**

I am trying to compile and run this on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS aarch64.

The output of the `lscpu` command is:

```
Architecture:            aarch64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:               ARM
  Model name:            Cortex-A72
    Model:               3
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per cluster: 4
    Socket(s):           -
    Cluster(s):          1
    Stepping:            r0p3
    CPU max MHz:         1800.0000
    CPU min MHz:         600.0000
    BogoMIPS:            108.00
    Flags:               fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
```

The target for `gcc` running in this environment is `aarch64-linux-gnu`. I understand that the Cortex-A72 has floating point hardware. I also know that the `-mfloat-abi=soft` flag is not supported on aarch64.

**What I'm trying to do**

I am trying to write a fixed-point arithmetic implementation of the C math atan() function. I would like to compare the runtime of my fixed-point implementation of this function, to atan(), where it's floating point operations are emulated in software routines, rather than executed on the FPU.

1. I have a `.c` file containing my fixed-point function implementation using integer arguments.
2. I have a `.c` reference file containing a call to atan() from the math library using floating point arguments

**Question**

Is there any way of telling GCC in this environment to assemble floating point instructions into emulations in software? Is this even possible? Or do I have to find a platform without floating-point hardware support to run this on?

I can compile my fixed-point implementation normally (no need for special flags, it contains no floating point instructions to be emulated).

I want to compile the reference function which involves floating point arguments, in such a way that it is actually translated to fixed-point assembly instructions emulating the floating-point behavior.

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: What requirements do you have that softfloat meets that hardfloat does not?

Comment: My understanding is that soft float emulates the floating point instructions using software (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html) Whereas hard float will compile using genuine floating point instructions, to be executed on hardware which supports such operations. 

If the call to atan() function is compiled using floating point operations I can’t perform the performance measurement which I need.

Comment: If you have issues getting the compiler to generate the code you want, then bypass the compiler and use assembly language to do exactly what you want done.  Use the mixed-output gcc option to get a C and asm mnemonics listing of sample code to get started.

Comment: That’s a solution I hadn’t considered. I will look into that thank you.

Comment: I suspect that gcc doesn't support this on AArch64.  Your link says that to use emulation, you should use `-msoft-float`, but that not all targets support this; and for me `-msoft-float` is unrecognized by gcc on AArch64.  It's not surprising: why would somebody spend time writing floating-point emulation for an architecture that is defined to always have hardware floating-point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no straightforward solution to do exactly what you've described. GCC on AArch64 does have the option `-mgeneral-regs-only` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/AArch64-Options.html#AArch64-Options) that will tell the compiler to avoid generating any FP/SIMD instructions, but if your source code has any floating-point arithmetic it will give you an error rather than trying to emulate it with fixed-point operations. The option exists for users like the Linux kernel where they want to avoid touching the FP/SIMD registers outside some very controlled contexts, and they don't use floating-point arithmetic in their code at all.

Furthermore, there is no defined soft-float ABI for AArch64, all portable software assumes that FP/SIMD is present and available for use. This is baked into things like the calling convention.
The GCC sources contain many floating-point emulation routines in `libgcc` that could act as building blocks for emulating many common floating-point operations, but the compiler for AArch64 is not wired up to use them, as they a soft-float AArch64 ABI is not supported

Comment: Would this be possible on an older `armv6l` 32-bit architecture? I also have access to an older Raspberry Pi Model B+ rev. 1.2.   

That runs on an ARM1176, `lscpu` reports the architecture as `armv6l`. Running the default Raspbian release (based on bullseye Debian), the default target for `gcc` is `arm-linux-gnueabihf`. 

Trying to compile a program with the `-mfloat-abi=soft` flag returns a different error;  

`error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory 7 | # include <gnu/stubs-soft.h>`.

Comment: Perhaps, if you're happy to use the 32-bit ISA (AArch32) instead of AArch64. For AArch32 there is a soft-float calling convention defined and tools support it through `-mfloat-abi=soft`. However, 32-bit Arm Linux systems are usually configured for the hard-float target (the `hf` in `arm-linux-gnueabihf`) and the error you're seeing is due to not having soft-float libraries installed with your compiler. You can try finding a bare-metal cross-compiler from https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/downloads that suits your needs though.